# Split characters from string by nth character python

Tags: python, string

I have two special type of strings(both consisting of lowercase English letters):
two_string : string of length 2(example: "ab","zz")
three_string : string of length 3(example : "abc","ghw")

I have to create new strings by placing one or several two_strings and three_strings side by side in a line and without placing two same strings next to one another.
From the example above you can create for example "abzz","ababc","zzabcghwab",etc..

the case is, i need to generate a list of possible two character and three characters from the input string

For example,

input_string = "abcdef"
output = ["ab","abc","cd","def","ef"], etc..

input_string1 = "abcdefg"
output1 = ["ab","abc","cd","cde","de","efg"] etc..

input_string2 = "ababcabc"
output2 = ["aba","abc","bc","bca","ab","ca"] etc..

input_string3 = "ccccacccc"
output3 =["cac","ccc"] etc..

```
def split_string(strg):
strg_len = len(strg)
output_strg = []
for x in range(0,len(strg)):
    x_2 = x+2
    x_3 = x+3
    two_ltr_com = strg[x:x_2]
    if(len(two_ltr_com) > 1):
        if(two_ltr_com not in output_strg):
            output_strg.append(two_ltr_com)
        if(x+3 <= len(strg)):
            three_ltr_com = strg[x:x_3]
            if(three_ltr_com not in output_strg):
                output_strg.append(three_ltr_com) 
return output_strg

result = split_string("abcdef")
print(result)
```

can anyone help me in this case? Thanks in advance

Comment: The examples don't make sense to be. E.g. Why is there no "bc" in the first example output?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @TomDalton Thanks for replying.. split functionality should happen for each two characters( i mean, if given string "abcdef", need to take first two character(ab) after need to take third character(c) as starting point to take next two characters)

Comment: Ok. Why is "ab" and "ca" missing from output2?

Comment: Sorry i missed that, now i updated that as well

Comment: @PremRexx Were you able to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's I'd do is have a loop that loops over the desired substring lengths. E.g in this case `for substr_len in (2, 3):`.

Within that loop, I'd use another loop to iterate over the string indexes. I'd gather all the matching strings in a `set`, which takes care of the duplicates (sets cannot contain duplicate items).

So as a rough sketch:

```
s = "abcdefghij"
substrings = set()
for substring_len in (2, 3):
    for idx in range(0, len(s), substring_len):
        ss = s[idx:idx+substring_len]
        substrings.add(ss)
```

The only other thing I think you need to think about then is how to handle input strings that are not of a length that cleanly divides by 12 - e.g. What does the 2-string[s] of "abc" look like?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time :). i ran above code for input_string1(abcdefg), i'm not getting all possible outputs and single character should not appear in output set. can you please run your code for input_string1 to check the result. :)

Comment: I get 'ab', 'abc', 'cd', 'def', 'ef', 'g'. As per my final sentence, I don't know how you need to handle strings that don't partition cleaning into 2- or 3- strings and the above code doesn't attempt to address that.

Comment: i got other logic to achieve that, i dont know how to write a code for that, can you please help me to write the code for my logic,

Comment: I can't, because I don't know what you want/need to do in that case.

Comment: logic is , if input_string "abcdefg" expected output is "ab"(2 characters), "abc"(3 charcters), "cd"(2 characters),"cde"(3 characters),"ef"(2 charcters),"efg"(3 characters),                        so the pattern is, first time in loop should extract 2 character from string, second time in loop should 3 characters, third time in loop should extract 2 character and so on..              if i'm able to write a code for this, i can solve the issue.. but i dont know, how to achieve this loop like above in python.. can you give some idea ?